# Sequence of smooth functions approximating a 2d cylinder step function

Tags: approximation

Let $f(x,y)=1$ if $(x,y)$ is in the unit disk and $f=0$ otherwise. I would like to approximate $f$ by a sequence of smooth functions. The functions need to be evaluated quickly so the results I'm getting from mollification are to awkward to deal with...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Wait... why did you remove the specific function? o_O

Comment: Oh whoops... I was editing... that was a mistake...

Comment: That's better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try any of formulae 17 to 27 in the [MathWorld page for the unit step function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html), since the function you're interested in is expressible as

$$1-H(x^2+y^2-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can convolve your function with a bivariate Gaussian density kernel, $\Phi(x,y; \sigma_x, \sigma_y)$, and obtain a smooth representation.  Then you can let the variance parameters $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ go to zero to obtain arbitrarily accurate approximation to $f(x,y)$.